# How do I delete a job class out of a deck?

Tags: mobius-final-fantasy

I accidently filled all my decks with the same job, how do I replace a job with a new one?

Answer (score 2):

If my memory serves me right (as I haven't played it recently) you need to tap the Job in Edit Deck, and when the jobs show up, you can select a new one to replace the one you set previously.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.